# The effect of the elementary column operations $C_{ij}$, $cC_i(c\neq 0)$ and $C_i+cC_j$, on an $m×n$ matrix $A$ is obtained by post multiplying $A$

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, transformation

I was studying matrices when I came accross the following theorem:

> The effect of the elementary column operations $C_{ij}$, $cC_i(c\neq 0)$ and $C_i+cC_j$, on an $m×n$ matrix $A$ is obtained by post multiplying $A$ by $(E_{ij})^t$, $(E_{i})^t$ and $(E_{ij}(c))^t$ respectively,  where each elementary matrix is of order $n$ .

The notations used above have their usual meanings.(I think these notations are standard if, they need clarity please do inform me, I will edit in the details about them )

My proof for the theorem goes like this:

> We consider a matrix $P$ of order $r×n$. Let the rows of $P$ are $P_1,P_2,P_3,...,P_r$ and let the columns of $A$ be $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$. Now, we consider the matrix $PA= \begin{pmatrix}
> P_1A_1 & P_1A_2 & ... & P_1A_n\\
> P_2A_1 & P_2A_2 & ... & P_2A_n\\
> ...\\
> P_rA_1 & P_rA_2 & ... & P_rA_n
> \end{pmatrix}$. Now, if we intercange the ith column of $A$ with the jth column then the transformed matrix is $C_{ij}(A)$ and if we consider the matrix $PC_{ij}(A)$, then, $PA$, also has its ith and jth row interchanged so we can say, $PC_{ij}(A)=C_{ij}(PA)$. Now, if we multiply a scalar $c\neq 0$ to a row of $A$, then, we denote this by $C_i(c)(A)$. We consider the matrix $PC_{i}(c)(A)$ . We find that then the matrix $PA$ also has its ith column multiplied by $c$ , and hence $PC_{i}(c)(A)=C_{i}(c)(PA)$. Again, we consider the column operation where $c$ times the  jth column of a matrix is added to ith column of the matrix. We denote this operation by $C_{ij}(c)(A)$. Now, we consider $PC_{ij}(c)(A)$. We find that the c times the jth column is added to the ith column in $PA$, when $A$ is tranformed under this operation and hence $PC_{ij}(c)(A)=C_{ij}(c)(PA)$. Thus we can write $C_{ij}(A)=C_{ij}(A.I)=AC_{ij}(I)=A.E_{ij}$. Similarly, $C_{i}(c)(A)=C_{i}(c)(A.I)=AC_{i}(c)(I)=AE_i(c)$ and $C_{ij}(c)(A)=C_{ij}(c)(A.I)=AC_{i}(c)(I)=AE_i(c)$.

Is the above proof correct? If so, then in the theorem above "$(E_{ij})^t$, $(E_{i})^t$ and $(E_{ij}(c))^t$" should actually be just "$(E_{ij})$, $(E_{i})$ and $(E_{ij}(c))$" (although I can't decipher what is meant by $(E_{ij})^t$, etc?) , correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof looks correct. The problem you have is with notation. Notice that the elementary matrices that interchange two $\textit{rows}$, $E_{ij}$, and multiply a row by a constant $c$, $E_{i}(c)$, are symmetric, so they also do the job for column operations. But this is not the case for the matrix giving the sum of the $i$th row and the $j$th row multiplied by a constant, $E_{ij}(c)$. If you do $AE_{ij}(c)$, then you are substituting the $i$th column, $C_i$, by $cC_i+C_j$, instead of $C_i+cC_j$. To remedy this, you just have to transpose, that is, take the product $A(E_{ij}(c))^{t}$.

Comment: @Camby Yeah, you are very much correct . Actually, I considered $E_{ij}$ to be the operation concerning the interchange of $ith$ and $jth$ columns and similarly I considered $E_{i}(c),$$E_{ij}(c)$ as operations concerning multiplication of $c$ with the ith column and $c×jth\space column +ith\space column $ respectively.  But as you noted I think they must be standard symbols denoting $only$ row operations and $not$ column operations , right?

Comment: @Camby If we consider $E_{ij}$, etc as column operations, then the proof is fully valid, right? However, can you please explain how is column operations $E_{ij}$ is same as $E_{ij}$ (this  $E_{ij}$ is considered as interchange of ith and jth rows)? I dont get this?I think $C_{ij}$(, which I considered with the symbol $E_{ij}$ in my proof) is actually equal to $E_{ij}^t$(this $E_{ij}$ is actually is a row operation  and $E_{ij}^t$ is actually the transpose of it )...

Comment: @Franklin I think that the symbols $E_{ij}$, and so on, are reserved for the elementary matrices performing the desired transformation for rows (that is why your reference take their transposes). I’d suggest you to take the explicit form of the matrices $E_{ij}$  (following your notation) and see what the resulting matrix $AE_{ij}$ is: you’ll see that it is exactly the matrix obtained by performing the desired column transformation. In addition, you’ll see by the way that the conclusion of your proof is an easy consequence of associativity of matrix product.

Comment: @Franklin if your reference uses $E_{ij}$ for row transformations, notice that a column transformation on a matrix $A$ is obtained performing the corresponding transformation of rows to $A^t$ and then transposing again. So, following your reference notation, a column transformation of $A$ would be obtained as $(E_{ij}A^t)^t=AE_{ij}^t$, and this is where the transpose of $E_{ij}$ comes from.

Comment: @Camby True , that my reference of $E_{ij}$ are reserved for the elementary matrices performing the desired transformation for rows and hence, they take their transposes, as you say . But , if I consider $E_{ij}$ to be the elementary matrix where  ith and jth $columns$ are interchanged ,i.e if I change the notion of $E_{ij}$,etc to  analogous operations concerning $columns$ and $not\space rows$, then my proof is correct (in every sense), right?...

Comment: @Franklin yes, it is correct.

Comment: @Camby Thank you so very much! This clears it up , so in short when using correct notation $C_{ij}=E_{ij}^t$, where $C_{ij}$ is the operation concerning the change of ith and jth column in an identity matrix, correct?...

Comment: @Franklin that’s the point, it’s all a matter of notation.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot...